# Decoding html on server side

Tags: jquery, asp.net, web-services

I have a string which I want to encode on client side using JavaScript:

```
/* JS code */
var blogBody = $(".editor").val();
var blogBodyEnc = encodeURIComponent(blogBody)
// blogBody = "<p>text</p><p><br></p><p><br></p><p>text</p>";
// blogBodyEnc = "%3Cp%3Etext%3C%2Fp%3E%3Cp%3E%3Cbr%3E%3C%2Fp%3E%3Cp%3E%3Cbr%3E%3C%2Fp%3E%3Cp%3Etext%3C%2Fp%3E"
```

Then I'm passing encoded string blogBodyEnc to server using jquery ajax. And now I want to decode this string on server. I'm trying:

```
/* ASP.NET code */
string msg = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(blogBodyEnc);
// blogBodyEnc = "%3Cp%3Etext%3C%2Fp%3E%3Cp%3E%3Cbr%3E%3C%2Fp%3E%3Cp%3E%3Cbr%3E%3C%2Fp%3E%3Cp%3Etext%3C%2Fp%3E"
// msg =         "%3Cp%3Etext%3C%2Fp%3E%3Cp%3E%3Cbr%3E%3C%2Fp%3E%3Cp%3E%3Cbr%3E%3C%2Fp%3E%3Cp%3Etext%3C%2Fp%3E"
```

Could anybody say what is wrong? I expecting to see html code after decoding on server side... but it still encoded.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want [`UrlDecode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httputility.urldecode.aspx), not `HtmlDecode`.

Comment: I'm confused.... I see that it really help me but what is the difference between UrlDecode and HtmlDecode? Could you please write how it work? I'm asking it because I used these functions earlier - but I encoded string on server side, and decoded at client side with JavaScript. And it worked perfect.

Comment: @Vytalyi: HTML-encoding is doing things like turning `&` into `&amp;` and such -- prepping text so that when output as part of an HTML document, the `&` comes out as an `&` and isn't confused with the beginning of a character entity. URI-encoding (sometimes called URL-encoding) is turning things like `&` into `%26` -- encoding text for transmission to the server. They do different things and for different reasons. Read the [`HtmlEncode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/73z22y6h.aspx) and [`URLEncode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4fkewx0t.aspx) pages to for more info.

Comment: But the OP is enconding HTML as if it were a URL. This is, at the very least, an odd decision. He should be encoding the value of the editor as HTML because that's what the editor holds. I am not even sure that URL encoding will encode properly all HTML values...

Comment: @Icarus: It will, in terms of sending the text on the wire. What the OP does with it once he/she has it depends on what he/she wants to do with it. *If* he/she wants to display it later in an HTML page, then of course at *that* point, he/she would want to HTML-encode it as part of prepping for display. But not prior (because, for instance, if you were to output them in plaintext, or an RTF, or a PDF, etc., you'd want the original text).

Comment: I have html message. I want to make chain of long convertings which will remove denied tags, clean html and so on... So I want to make these convertings on server side, and return clean HTML back to client. But it should be HTML which I want to show as a preview to user.

Answer (score 1):

I think he really wants:

```
function htmlEncode(value){
   return $('<div/>').text(value).html();
}
```

And call it as so:

```
var blogBodyEnc = htmlEncode($(".editor").val());
```

To then use

```
string msg = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(blogBodyEnc);
```

Adding sample [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/S32dQ/)

Comment: Not exactly... I don't want to wrap it with div. I want to encode it.

Comment: Who says that the returned value from htmlEncode will be wrapped in a div? See this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/S32dQ/

Comment: Yeah, looks like it also encode my html. Really good solution. Thanks!